# How to make (and restore) an application snapshot in runtime?

Tags: linux, virtualization, snapshot

I'm trying to make a snapshot of a running application, in runtime, and restore it afterwards. By 'snapshot' I mean complete state of my application - I suppose that's just memory pages and CPU registers, but I may be wrong.

This is a console application on Linux (Debian, to be exact) running in one of my tty's. These 'snapshots' will be used in the same session without reboot.
Right now the only solution I know about is running that application in VM and using snapshots provided by it, but I hope there are more lightweight solutions to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is ***application checkpointing*** (try search for it on Google) and you can use [CRIU](https://criu.org) that makes possible to do more advanced things, like restore an application after a system reboot (even changing system properties) or migrate application execution on another machine (or more machines).

There is also [Linux-CR](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~orenl/papers/ols2010-linuxcr.pdf) but don't know if it's a still active project.

Comment: Thank you, seems to be it! Going to test that a little bit later and confirm for sure.